# gstreamer hls stream and receive

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, http-live-streaming

## Question

How do I need to tweak the gstreamer pipeline to receive HLS streams in my applicaton.

## Setup

So far, the streaming part looks like this

```sh
$ gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=true ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink &
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 5000
```

I can confirm that the streaming works using VLC and a gstreamer fakesink

```sh
# See end of post for output of this command
$ gst-launch-1.0 -v souphttpsrc is-live=true location=http://localhost:5000/playlist.m3u8 ! hlsdemux ! tsdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! fakesink dump=1
```

However, when trying to tie in the stream into my Darknet using the `appsink` instead of `fakesink` I get no image.

### Debugging Darknet

Darknet itself seems to work fine with the `appsink` as file inputs using the pipe

```
some_file_name.mp4
```

and USB webcam using

```
v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-raw, framerate=30/1, width=640, height=360 ! videoconvert ! appsink
```

work just fine.

### Output of `fakesink`

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Got context from element 'souphttpsrc0': gst.soup.session=context, session=(SoupSession)NULL, force=(boolean)false;
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTSDemux:tsdemux0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(int)188
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)nal
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, chroma-format=(string)4:4:4, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)high-4:4:4, level=(string)1.3, codec_data=(buffer)01f4000dffe1001d67f4000d919b28283f602d41804150000003001000000303c8f142996001000568ebec4480
Redistribute latency...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/avdec_h264:avdec_h264-0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, chroma-format=(string)4:4:4, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)high-4:4:4, level=(string)1.3, codec_data=(buffer)01f4000dffe1001d67f4000d919b28283f602d41804150000003001000000303c8f142996001000568ebec4480
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/avdec_h264:avdec_h264-0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)Y444, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)Y444, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFakeSink:fakesink0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)Y444, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)Y444, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)30/1
Redistribute latency...
00000000 (0x7f402d2220): eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb  ................
00000010 (0x7f402d2230): eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb  ................
00000020 (0x7f402d2240): eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb eb d2 d2 d2  ................
00000030 (0x7f402d2250): d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2  ................
00000040 (0x7f402d2260): d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2  ................
00000050 (0x7f402d2270): d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 d2 aa aa aa aa aa  ................
00000060 (0x7f402d2280): aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  ................
00000070 (0x7f402d2290): aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  ................
00000080 (0x7f402d22a0): aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa 91 91 91 91 91 91 91  ................
00000090 (0x7f402d22b0): 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91  ................
000000a0 (0x7f402d22c0): 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91  ................
000000b0 (0x7f402d22d0): 91 91 91 91 91 91 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a  ......jjjjjjjjjj
000000c0 (0x7f402d22e0): 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a  jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj
000000d0 (0x7f402d22f0): 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a 6a  jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj
000000e0 (0x7f402d2300): 6a 6a 6a 6a 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51  jjjjQQQQQQQQQQQQ
000000f0 (0x7f402d2310): 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51  QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
00000100 (0x7f402d2320): 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51  QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
```